# Can anyone please explain L3 SVI configuration ,What is SVI and Where do we use it?

Tags: vlan, switching, cisco-nexus, switching-modes

I am learning about switching and came across SVI in vlans ,I Googled and watched couple videos and got really confusing Firsly where do we use Svi? and why do we use it,How to configure svi and what are the benefits of using svi, How to determine svi on a cisco or Nexus Switch .please any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

An SVI is a Switched Virtual Interface. It is an interface for the VLAN itself on the switch. It can be a layer-3 interface (IP addressing) to allow the switch itself to participate in the VLAN.

A layer-2 switch can use a layer-3 SVI as its management interface, and it would also need a default gateway in the VLAN to allow the management interface to be reached from other networks through the router at the default gateway address.

For a layer-3 switch, a layer-3 SVI is a gateway for the VLAN. It is a virtual router interface, allowing traffic from the VLAN of the SVI to be routed to and from other networks, e.g. other layer-3 SVIs or router interfaces configured on the layer-3 switch.

Comment: Great ! Thx for the info.

Answer (score 1):

On Cisco devices, SVI's are configured just like a physical interface.  They are named for the vlan they're attached to.

For example, the SVI for Vlan 10 is named `interface vlan10`.  To assign an IPv4 address to it, you would type:

```
interface vlan10
ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Great ! Thx for the info.